# Extraer datos en r y convertirlos en dataframe

Tags: r

```
"[1] "[DIEGO ALVARADO - 20/09/2019] BUENAS TARDES ME GUSTARÍA INFORMACIÓN 89908945 [KAREN SOLIS - 20/09/2019] PRECIO? [KAREN SOLIS - 22/09/2019] CUANTOS CUARTOS? [KAREN SOLIS - 23/09/2019] ??? [MAUREN ROJAS - 29/09/2019] ME INTERESA LA CASA, INFORMACIÓN A MAUREN_ROJAS@GMAIL.COM [PEDRO FONSECA - 2/10/2019] 22-90-33-25 DEJO MI TELEFONO PARA QUE ME ENVIEN INFORMACIÓN [MARCO MARIN - 2/10/2019] SE ADMITEN MASCOTAS? [MARCO MARIN- 2/10/2019] QUE DIA PODRÍA VISITAR EL LUGAR 88499535 [DIEGO ALVARADO - 2/10/2019] INFORMACIÓN POR FAVOR A 89908945 [JOHN ELIZONDO - 3/10/2019] ME INTERESA PASENME INFORMACION [KATALINA SEGURA - 3/10/2019] CUANTAS HABITACIONES TIENE? [MARCOS CRUZ - 3/10/2019] 27839090, PUEDO VISITAR LA CASA MAÑANA? [FLOR CAMBRONERO - 5/10/2019] INFO FLOR82@HOTMAIL.COM [MARCO PONCE - 5/10/2019] EL PRECIO ES NEGOCIABLE? [LUIS SANCHEZ - 5/10/2019] INFORMACIÓN, INFO@TRANSPORTESSANCHEZ.COM [CARMEN BALERO - 5/10/2019] NOS INTERESA PARA PASARNOS ESTE MISMO FIN DE SEMANA, 89990878 o 25324040 [MARTA FLORES- 10/10/2019] A QUE NUMERO LLAMO PARA COORDINAR UNA VISITA? LLAMENME AL 8546-0050 [LUIS SANCHEZ - 10/10/2019] LLAMENME AL 22627070"
```

De este texto, extraje los nombres, fechas, mensajes y correos, con `str_extract` pero al extraerlos en dataframnes distintos, no tienen la misma longitud, porque - por ejemplo- no todas las personas tienen un numero o un email.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los datos extraidos se unan en un solo data frame y cada dato vaya con su respectivo nombre?.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow en español! Bienvenido Paulina Cubillo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Agrega en tu pregunta el código que tienes hasta ahora para extraer los datos, eso hará seguramente mas clara tu pregunta.

Comment: Si los datos que estás poniendo son nombres y números de teléfono reales, te recomendaría que los cambiases para no meterte en líos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mezclar dos dataFrames por columnas que se llaman igual puedes usar la función `merge()`

```
nuevoDataFrame <- merge(dataFrame1, dataFrame2)
```

Imagínate que el dataFrame1 tiene las columnas *id, name, telefono* y el dataFrame2 tiene las columnas *id* y *mail*

El **merge()** hará el macheo por la columna *id* y lo fusionará en un nuevo dataFrame.

Comment: Bienvenido Juan, sería recomendable que aportaras código a tu respuesta indicando cómo se realiza el merge, los enlaces como respuestas están mal vistos porque el día que el enlace no funcione, tu respuesta dejará de servirle a otras personas.